# How to include logarithm function in calculation?

Tags: math, react-native, formula, logarithm

I am using react-native to build my mobile app and one of the feature include using a formula to calculate a result.

The formula includes log function as seen below:

[image]

How can I include log function into my calculation code?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log

Comment: A simple search of "logarithms in javascript" gives you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Math.log() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log).

```
(459 / (1.0324- (0.19077 * (Math.log((abdomen-neck) + (0.15456 * Math.log(height) )))))) - 450
```

It would make sense to save each of the brackets into a variable and compute more clearly

Comment: Be careful though as `Math.log` is a natural log and not base-10. OP should use `Math.log10` instead